# Copy an embeded OLEObject to a file with VBA without opening application

Tags: vba

I have an Excel document with a PPT embeded.
I would like to create a VBA sub that will copy this file to the `filepath` folder:

```
Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application

Dim Filepath As String
Filepath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Dim File As PowerPoint.Presentation
' Worksheet(1).OLEObjects(1).Verb xlOpen
Set File = Worksheet(1).OLEObjects.Object
File.SaveAs Filepath & "\ppt.pptx", PowerPoint.ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation, msoTriStateMixed
```

If I leave the line commented, I get the error:

```
Run-time error 1004, Unable to get Object Property of OLEObject class
```

But If I uncomment it, PowerPoint will launch before saving the file.

Comment: Sorry not going to happen. Unless you want to try and open the file in binary read mode and look for the embedded Excel filename extension, work backwards from there and pull the file name. Two problems - Typically an embedded file does not retain the full file path and if it is stored, there's no guarantee the filename will be in readable text

Comment: In order to save the file, using the PowerPoint object model, PowerPoint must be open and running. Your only other option would be to leverage the Office Open XML file formats. The PowerPoint presentation should be completely stored in the Excel file and therefore it's possible to extract it - from the *closed* Excel workbook.